# able to create thumbnails with PIL but my multiprocessing code does not create PIL thumbnails

Tags: python, multiprocessing, python-imaging-library

I am trying to learn how to use multiprocessing with PIL using python 2.7 on a  64 bit windows 7 pc.

I can successfully create (and save) the thumbnails using PIL to the desired location on my pc. When I try to implement multiprocessing, my code does not create any thumbnails and it loops through the files about twice as fast. I have about 9,000 image files in multiple directories and sub directories (I have no control over the file names not directory structure)

here is the basis of the code that works.

```
from multiprocessing import Pool, freeze_support
import os
from fnmatch import fnmatch
from timeit import default_timer as timer
from PIL import Image, ImageFile

starttime = timer()

SIZE = (125, 125)
SAVE_DIRECTORY = r'c:\path\to\thumbs'
PATH = r'c:\path\to\directories\with\photos

def enumeratepaths(path):
    """ returns the path of all files in a directory recursively"""

def create_thumbnail(_filename):
    try:
        ImageFile.LOAD_TRUNCATED_IMAGES = True
        im = Image.open(_filename)
        im.thumbnail(SIZE, Image.ANTIALIAS)
        base, fname = os.path.split(_filename)
        outfile = os.path.split(_filename)[1] + ".thumb.jpg"
        save_path = os.path.join(SAVE_DIRECTORY, outfile)
        im.save(save_path, "jpeg")
    except IOError:
        print " cannot create thumbnail for ... ",_filename


if __name__ == '__main__':
    freeze_support() # need this in windows; no effect in *nix

    for _path in enumeratepaths(PATH):
        if fnmatch(_path, "*.jpg"):
            create_thumbnail(_path)
            # pool = Pool()
            # pool.map(create_thumbnail, _path)
            # pool.close()
            # pool.join()
```

The code works and creates the 9,000 thumbnails in the desired location. When I comment out create_thumbnail(_path) and un-comment the multiprocessing code, the code iterates thru the directory structure twice as fast but does not create any thumbnails. How would I adjust the multiprocessing code to make it work?

Comment: I played and searched some more...for a strange reason the chosen directory will not accept the thumbnails and the code "pool.map(create_thumbnail, _path)" needs to be pool.map(create_thumbnail(_path), _path) to create the thumbnails ( after pointing the save directory to a new location )

Answer (score 0, accepted):

the code "pool.map(create_thumbnail, _path)" needs to be pool.map(create_thumbnail(_path), _path) to create the thumbnails

Comment: the code works... time to create 9000 thumbnails from a network storage with multiprocessing was 12,235 seconds...time to process same images without multiprocessing 9,537 seconds...not sure why multiprocessing took more time